# How to alter a single property when fetching a set of objects with EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Suppose we're fetching a bunch of accounts but we want to hide the numbers. Is there a way to set each element's property *A* to something?

```
IEnumerable<Account> accounts = context.Accounts;
foreach(Account accout = accounts)
  account.Number = Guid.Empty;
return accounts;
```

I'd like to see something like this pseudocode.

```
return context.Accounts
  .Alter(account => account.Number = Guid.Empty);
```

Comment: Use a [projection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386943(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Jasen Care to elaborate a bit? I've visited the link provided but got no wiser...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<Account> accounts = context.Accounts;
accounts.Foreach(account => { account.Number = Guid.Empty; });
return accounts;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

```
return context.Account.ToArray().Select(acc=>
{
  acc.Number=Guid.Empty; 
  return acc;
});
```

You can only do this in memory, so this will be not a database select.

Another approach could be creating a View in database with this column as empty guide and selecting directly from it.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot move the "replace"  logic to database with Linq to Entity Framework, simply because this is an operation on the object. Database view or anonymous object select (explicitly selecting only desired field with the number skipped)   are your best option

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
var accounts = context.Accouts
  .Select(a => new Account
  {
    Number = Guid.Empty,
    Prop1 = a.Prop1,
    // map other properties
  });
```

Comment: Well, that's what I do now. But if the object has a lot of properties and I only need to change a single one, it's all kind of depressingly ineffective... I was hoping for a shortie here.   :)

Comment: Coding time. I'll need to do that for a bunch of objects. And they're loooong.